# Showing a complex inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

Let $z,w \in \mathbb C$ s.t $\bar z w \neq 1$ and $|z|\leq 1, |w| \leq 1$ then $ |\dfrac{z-w}{1-\bar z w}| \leq 1$

The hint is to show that $ |z-w|^2\leq |1-\bar z w|^2$ but i cant relate those 2

Comment: Hint: Expand both products using the definition of $|\cdot|^2$.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/734804/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/450822/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/378074/42969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that $|z|^2 = z \overline z$. Then,we have

$ |z - \overline \omega |^2 \le |1 - \overline z w|^2 \iff (z - \overline \omega) (\overline z - \omega) \le (1 - \overline z w) (1 - z \overline w) \iff z \overline z - z \overline \omega - \omega \overline \ + \omega \overline \omega \le 1 - z \overline \omega - \overline z \omega + z \overline z \omega \overline \omega $

After simplifying, the equivalence arrives at

$|z|^2 + |\omega|^2 <=  1 + |z|^2 |x|^2 \iff (|x| ^ 2 - 1) * (|y| ^ 2 - 1) \ge 0$, which is true since we assumed $|x| \le 1$ and $|y| \le 1$, so $|x| ^ 2 \le 1$ and $ |y| ^ 2 \le 1 $. So, we have proven the hint

Finally, since both terms are positive divide  to get the conclusion squared. And since, the absolute value is always positive, you can get rid of the square, to get the desired conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

$$|1-\overline zw|^2=(1-\overline zw)(1-\overline wz)=1+|wz|^2-\overline z w-\overline wz,$$
$$|z-w|^2=(z-w)(\overline z-\overline w)=|z|^2+|w|^2-z\overline w-w\overline z.$$
The difference is
$$1+|wz|^2-|w|^2-|z|^2.$$

Comment: The difference can be factored as $$(1-|z|)(1-|w|)(1+|z|)(1+|w|),$$ which makes the positivity immediately apparent.